# Do weapons with passive effects need to be in-hand/off-hand to take effect?

Tags: elden-ring

I was looking into weapon skills, and came across the "[Regal Roar](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Regal+Roar)" skill, unique to the Axe of Godfrey. It specifies what parts of the attacks are affected by what talismans, etc. and then I notice that it is also affected by the [Highland Axe's](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Highland+Axe) passive effect:

> Passively increases the damage of Roars by 10%. Stacks with Roar Medallion, but does not stack with another Highland Axe.

Now, normally you would assume that the AoG would be used with two hands, which means the HA would be holstered. Does this negate the passive of this weapon at all? Additionally, if I were to equip it in my list, but not actually have it in my hand/holstered, does that take effect?

Comment: That's how it worked in Dark Souls. Certain weapons/shields are used in the offhand while two-handing for the passive boosts. They do need to be visible (i.e. on your character's back), not in another hand slot. I can't confirm Elden Ring didn't change things, but I would be surprised if they did.